# htaccess a wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Im trying to secure my wordpress site behind htaccess but seem to be getting a fail.

**HTML**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile www.sample.com/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "A fail" is a very descriptive error message for us to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

The `AuthUserFile` value is always specific to your hosting configuration. If you don't know what the value should be, do a `phpinfo()` and find the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value.

It should be sth like that:

`AuthUserFile /home/YOUR_NAME_ETC/.htpasswd`